# Change radio button's name dynamically

Tags: angularjs

In my code,by looping, two groups of radio button will be created.
For example,

```
 RadioButton1:  a.Yes b.no

 RadioButton2:  a.Yes b.no
```

The problem is, I am unable to change the name of radio button dynamically.So, when I check in one radio button in a group, other group's element is being checked.

My code is-

```
<div ng-repeat="t in getTimes(2) track by $index">
    <div>
        <div>
            <div ng-repeat="radioButton in 
                                  selection.head.avarageOrBestCount">s
                <input type="radio"  name="
                                   {{"avarageOrBestCount"+$parent.$index}}" 
                  value="{{radioButton}}" ng-model="ss"> {{radioButton}}<br>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I need to work name="{{"avarageOrBestCount"+$parent.$index}}". How can I change name of radio button dynamically??

Comment: Try to appen to the name index from parent repear/scope as well

Comment: $parent.$index ...  yah .. I have tried it....but its not working

Comment: Try this variant : 
name="avarageOrBestCount{{$parent.$index}}"

Comment: Thnak you @Natiq ... its working....

Comment: @ishmam shahriar, you are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are breaking the attribute string. Change this...

```
name="{{"avarageOrBestCount"+$parent.$index}}"
```

To this...

```
name="{{'avarageOrBestCount'+$parent.$index}}"
```

Use single-quotes within double-quotes " ' ' "  or viceversa.